# Excel And Statement to Display Shape

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

might be a simple ask but I am new around here & stumped!

If a cell contains a value, one shape is to show & one is to disappear, but I can't get the following code to do anything with the second shape. See below:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
     If Range("M17").Value = "Option A" Then
          Me.Shapes("Logo1").Visible = True And Me.Shapes("Logo3").Visible = False
          Else
           If Range("M17").Value = "Option B" Then
          Me.Shapes("Logo3").Visible = True And Me.Shapes("Logo1").Visible = False
            Else
            Me.Shapes("Logo3").Visible = False And Me.Shapes("Logo1").Visible = False
     End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `And` is a boolean operator put the two commands on separate lines without an `And`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Warcupine, `And` is a boolean operator and usually used in conditional statements (eg in `If` or `While`)

What you want to have is two different statements:

```
 Me.Shapes("Logo1").Visible = True 
 Me.Shapes("Logo3").Visible = False
```

If you insinst, you can put them on the same line by using `:` to separate both statements, but I would strongly advice against it:

```
Me.Shapes("Logo1").Visible = True : Me.Shapes("Logo3").Visible = False
```

You can, however, make your code easier:

```
Dim option as String 
option = Range("M17").Value 
Me.Shapes("Logo1").Visible = (option = "Option A")
Me.Shapes("Logo3").Visible = (option = "Option B")
```

The term `(option = "Option A")` resolves in either `True` or `False` and you can assign the result directly to the `Visible`-property

Comment: Thank you so much FunThomas! This worked great!